# How to make charArray that doesn't separate diacritics?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, normalization, diacritics, hebrew

I'm trying to separate a Hebrew word into letters in C#, but ToCharArray() separates the diacritics as if they're separate letters (which they're not). I'm fine with either keeping the letters whole with their diacritics, or worst case getting rid of the diacritics altogether.

Example: כֶּלֶב is coming out as 6 different letters.

Comment: Does `word.Length()` gives you the correct value?

Comment: Post an example. There are normalization functions but it's quite possible the diacritics *are* separate characters. Unicode allows specific characters to appear one over the other

Comment: @GeekyQuentin word.Length is counting the diacritics as seperate letters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos כֶּלֶב is an example. 3 letter word, it coming out as 6

Comment: I have taken an example of a name with diacritics and it turned out that they are not getting separated. Can you take a look at [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WD3AP7) and tell me if I was mistaken anywhere?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin try it with the word I just posted, it seperates it into 6 letters

Comment: They are separate letters, and when you use non-separate letters this is a denormalized string. Perhaps you can strip diacritics. Why do you need them like this anyway?

Comment: They are multiple `char` .. try writing `char y = 'לֶ';` or `char x = 'כֶּ';` -> No you simply can not force a symbol that is combined of 2 or 3 `char` into a single `char` ... nevertheless, interesting case though ;)

Comment: @Charlieface one use case I can think of might e.g. be "letter by letter" animations ^^

Comment: @derHugo it's essentially "letter by letter animations" like Charlieface said, the problem is if you use "Trim()" on the whole string it _doesn't_ remove the diacritics, as if they're one letter, but when you split it into chars all of the sudden you can iterate over them as different letters

Comment: `Trim` is for whitesapce so don't see how that's relevant. Yes they are different letters, but the font will specify how to produce the glyph overlapping the previous letter. So you need to draw the string, then scroll the result

Answer (score 5):

The [StringInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.stringinfo) class knows about base characters and accents and can handle this:

```
string s = "כֶּלֶב";
System.Globalization.TextElementEnumerator charEnum = System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);
while (charEnum.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(charEnum.GetTextElement());
}
```

will print 3 lines:

> כֶּ
> לֶ
> ב

Answer (score 3):

Strings in C# are stored as arrays of `char`. That is to say: they are arrays of UTF-16 code units. `ToCharArray()` just returns that UTF-16 array. And it sometimes takes multiple code units to form a single "symbol".

Would [`char.GetUnicodeCategory(char)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getunicodecategory?view=net-6.0) be of any help? Maybe you could split that array on `OtherLetter` or something (not familiar with Hebrew)?

```cs
const string word = "כֶּלֶב";
Console.WriteLine(word.Length);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", word.ToCharArray().Select(x => (int)x)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", word.ToCharArray().Select(char.GetUnicodeCategory)));
```

Output:

```
6
1499 1468 1462 1500 1462 1489
OtherLetter NonSpacingMark NonSpacingMark OtherLetter NonSpacingMark OtherLetter
```

Comment: interesting! So basically you would need to combine them until reaching the next `OtherLetter` item

Comment: @derHugo I _think_ so. You might have to try it on for size. But I really like [Hans's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211023/3063273) above and I +1'd it. Maybe you'd only need to resort to `char.GetUnicodeCategory` if you need really low-level control